# How to setup a proxy middleware in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, middleware

I have been working on a React app for a considerable amount of time. Recently, I noticed a particular issue. While I'm aware that it's possible to set up a proxy middleware in the development server, I'm unsure if the same can be done for production. The problem is that I can see all the API endpoints, along with the payload and response, in the network console of the browser. I want to conceal the actual API endpoints and the associated payload. I've searched the internet for solutions and found some tools and resources that allow setting up a proxy middleware on development servers or local machines. Now, I want to implement a proxy middleware for production.

On local machines, I successfully set up a proxy for the React app, but I'm unsure about how to send requests to API endpoints and retrieve the responses. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in this matter. If there are any available resources, they would be extremely helpful.

For your reference, I have included the configuration file below. I used the 'http-proxy-middleware' package to set up the proxy in the React app.

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/api1', createProxyMiddleware(
        {
            target: 'https://book.com/retrive-details/',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api1': ''
            }
        })
    );

    app.use('/api2', createProxyMiddleware(
        {
            target: 'https://book.com/send-details/',
            changeOrigin: true,
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api2': ''
            }
        })
    );
};
```

The provided code only covers the frontend configuration. I'm uncertain about how to pass data to the backend using a proxy in a production environment. My backend stack utilizes Laravel and Apache.

Comment: "*I want to conceal the actual API endpoints and the associated payload.*" - why? What do you mean by "actual endpoints" and how would you differentiate them from "fake endpoints"? Either way you provide an API endpoint that works the same no matter what URLs are used. And no, it is impossible to conceal the payload.

Comment: I want the API endpoints to be proxied. Internally, it will use a proxy to call the API endpoints. I just have a thought. This strategy may have been utilized in one of the GitHub repos.

Let me share you the link

Comment: I believe the concept I mentioned earlier has been implemented in this repository: https://github.com/knadh/listmonk. When running it locally and exploring the documentation, I discovered the usage of proxy middleware. This led me to consider whether a similar approach can be applied in a production environment.

Comment: Yes, reverse proxies are commonly used in production as well, but their purpose is organisation of the API endpoints (if you have many) and routing to different services (if you have multiple). Their purpose is not to hide anything. Proxies are a means, not an end. So again, why do you think you need one?

Comment: Indeed, you're correct. I believe I misunderstood the concept initially. I thought it would add an extra security layer to the API request. 

Any way Now I want a middleware to handle all the API requests and responses and to deploy the same concept on production, Can you help me with that in react js application?

Comment: Whether you use react on the frontend or not does not matter for the API itself, it will handle arbitrary clients. Or are you planning to use server-side rendering? Either way, if you want to add a middleware, again the question is: what do you want this middleware to do?

Comment: @string1301 did you got any solution for your problem.

Comment: A similar usecase which I am having is to hide specific APIs which are meant to fetch access token and having sensitive data like client id and secret in the authorization headers - so, I need to have something like proxying the requests in production ?